# Get parent DIV of HREF in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the parent div of the hyperlink clicked. In the example below, this would be `'.link-container'`. However, `this.parent` or `this.parents` does not work.

```
jQuery('.link-container a').live('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert(this.parent);
});
```

Any ideas on how to get this?.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your using it wrong. You have to wrap `this` in a jQ object. And parent is a function so you must call it as `parent()`:

```
$('.link-container a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parent());
});
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. I slightly modified your code to get the class: `alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));`. It worked for me.

Comment: Oh, yeah, lol `alert($(this).parent())` will alert an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).parent()
```

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0):

`.live` is deprecated, use `.on` if you are using the jquery version 1.7+ or else use `.delegate`, wrap `this` in the jquery object and then use the jquery method `parent` or `parents`

```
jQuery(document).delegate('.link-container a','click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert($(this).parents('.link-container'));
});
```

if the anchor tag is inside the `.lin-container` like

```
<div class='link-container'>
 <a href='#'>stack overflow</a>
</div>
```

you can use `closest`

```
jQuery(document).delegate('.link-container a','click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).closest('.link-container'));
    });
```

Comment: Thx for the heads-up on `.live`. However, `.on` never worked for me. I'll start another post in that regards. For this one, I have the anchor tag inside the div and needed to obtain the class for the same. So, I went with slightly modified code by elclanrs

Answer (score 0):

John, use either the raw javascript property `this.parentNode` or the jQuery method `$(this).parent()` which returns a jQuery object containing a collection of just one node (the parent node.)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

Say you have a parent div

```
<div id="parent">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">Click me</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".link").click(function(){
     alert(this.parentNode.id);
   });
});
```

I normally prefer parentNode over parent